# Laravel viewing picture in local disk

Tags: php, laravel

I am making like a dropbox clone for a school project, i made an upload fuction that uploads to the local disk so it cant be accessed by everyone.

Upload Function

```
public function updatedUpload($upload){
$object = $this->currentTeam->objects()->make(['parent_id' => $this->object->id]);
$object->objectable()->associate(
    $this->currentTeam->files()->create([
        'name' => $upload->getClientOriginalName(),
        'size' => $upload->getSize(),
        'path' => $upload->storePublicly('files', ['disk' => 'local'])
    ])
);

$object->save();
$this->object = $this->object->fresh();
```

}

But I want to put it in an  in the home.blade.

How do I make this and only the person who uploaded it can access it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific link for the user that can see this resource.

For example in your `routes/web.php`

```php
Route::get('/private_resource',[\App\Http\Controllers\PrivateResource::class, 'getLocalResource'])
->name('get_private_resource')->middleware('auth');
```

Define `PrivateResource` controller

```
class PrivateResource
{
    public function getLocalResource($filename){
        // Get your resource, for example
        $file = File::where('name', $filename)->first();

        // Check whether user can access this resource
        // For example
        if(\Auth::id() != $file->user_id) abort(403);

        return \Storage::disk('local')->download($filename);
    }
}
```

**Extra:** If you want extra privacy, you can use signed route using below function.

```
\URL::signedRoute('get_private_resource');
```

And add `signed` middleware to your route

```
Route::get('/private_resource',[\App\Http\Controllers\PrivateResource::class, 'getLocalResource'])
->name('get_private_resource')->middleware('auth','signed');
```

Comment: But i don't want to download it, i want to view it in an image

Comment: So, you can get it's content using `\Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);`

Comment: The thing is, in my database the file path is files/QvzsEzIMaX0LdESDZ0BSiW9aPM35Vz5s3dq4T0yU.png if i put that in ex: http://my-site.com/storage/files/QvzsEzIMaX0LdESDZ0BSiW9aPM35Vz5s3dq4T0yU.png i can't access it, i get 404

Comment: It is normal, as you're trying to protect your file from public access, so you must not access it like this. You should get it's content from a route that has some midllewares.